# Changing background image in TeeChart Delphi XE8 at run-time

Tags: delphi, teechart, delphi-xe8

I would like to use the gallery pictures (Metal, Wood, Stone, Clouds, etc.) which are available at design time under Chart/Panel/Image/Gallery.

If I set it at design time, I can easily disable it at run time with:

```
 g.backImage := nil;
```

But if I want to set it to a particular value, e.g. with

```
 g.backImage := 'metal';
```

I get an 'Incompatible types' error, because the compiler requires a TBackImage value. I do not have the source codes, and I cannot find the appropriate values on several Google searches.

Thinking that it *could* be just an enum, I tried typecasting it to one:

```
 g.backImage := TBackImage(1);
```

But it generates an exception. I also tried to "guess" the names, like tbiMetal, tbMetal, tMetal, and so on, to no avail...

What are those values?! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

`TBackImage` is a class whose methods you must call.

```
Chart.BackImage.LoadFromFile('full/path/to/imagefile');
```

Comment: Ok, so those patterns in the "gallery" section are real files, and are not already embedded in the object? I just want to be sure, because I am more than happy with them, and I'd like to avoid inserting another external file if not needed. Thank you.

Comment: @ZioBit yes, they are accessible via TBrushDialog class. Please see my reply.

Answer (score 1):

Those are real texture images embedded in TBrushDialog, they can be used/accessed like this:

```
uses TeeBrushDlg;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var BrushDialog: TBrushDialog;
begin
  BrushDialog:=TBrushDialog.Create(Self);
  Chart1.BackImage.Graphic:=BrushDialog.ImageCarbon.Picture.Graphic;
end;
```